# How to delete multiline string with grep

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

Let's say I have `file.txt` with following content (simplified for example. In real it's much more complex):

```
This line I DON'T want to remove \
    common substring

This line I want to remove \
    common substring
```

I tried

```
mv file.txt __file.txt
grep -vwE "This line I want" __file.txt > file.txt
rm __file.txt
```

to re-create `file.txt` and remove the whole `'This line I want to remove common substring'` with the line brake, but as output I get

```
This line I DON'T want to remove \
    common substring


    common substring
```

I can't use `grep -vwE "common substring" __file.txt > file.txt` additionally cause it will affect another multi-line string...

So how to make grep remove the whole multi-line considering line brake?

Comment: Are there an arbitrary number of line continuations? Or just 1?

Comment: Are the desired and undesired parts really contiguous blocks separated by one or more lines of whitespace, as shown in your example? If so, that opens up some "paragraph mode" options with perl and awk. Can you use `pcregrep`?

Comment: @glennjackman There is an exact number of line continuations. Line split into 8 lines should be deleted

Comment: @steeldriver it is the long `bash` command split by parameters to make it readable

Answer (score 1):

> Line split into 8 lines should be deleted

If there is a blank line separating each "paragraph", then you can write

```sh
awk -F '\n' -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NF != 8'
```

Demo:

```sh
cat <<"END" | awk -F'\n' -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NF != 8'
This line I DON'T want to remove \
    common substring

This line I want to remove \
    common substring \
    3 \
    4 \
    5 \
    6 \
    7 \
    8

Last line
END
```

```
This line I DON'T want to remove \
    common substring

Last line
```

---

Note that the bash `read` builtin can obey line continuations, but their positions are obliterared:

```sh
while IFS= read line; do declare -p line; done << "END"
This line I DON'T want to remove \
    common substring

This line I want to remove \
    common substring \
    3 \
    4 \
    5 \
    6 \
    7 \
    8

Last line
END
```

```
declare -- line="This line I DON'T want to remove     common substring"
declare -- line=""
declare -- line="This line I want to remove     common substring     3     4     5     6     7     8"
declare -- line=""
declare -- line="Last line"
```